# Permission denied accessing top.location.hostname

Tags: javascript, userscripts

When I access `top.location.hostname` through a userscript or Firefox add-on, I get the following in the Error Console:

> Error: Permission denied to access property 'hostname'

What is the problem with this and how to over come?

Edit:
`alert(location.hostname)` gives multiple alerts for a single webpage (may be, because of frames in a page).

So, I tried with `top.location.hostname`. It is giving correct output but with an error in error console. How to skip the error?

Comment: That code won't work from a cross-domain iframe, but this question needs a whole lot more detail!  Give us a recipe to duplicate the problem, at a minimum.

Comment: var host=top.location.hostname;
console.log("host: "+host); this is my simple userscript. It is displaying correct output in log and above mentioned error in console.